# How to get a list of email addresses from on-premise Exchange Server in Python?

Tags: python, exchange-server

I am attempting to retrieve a list of all email addresses in an enterprise domain from the company's Exchange server using Python. I am guessing that I would need to use some kind of Admin API to retrieve said information. I am looking at `PyExchange` and some others but I am unable to find specific areas where I can get started.

It would be great to get some advice on where I need to start with this.

PS - One of the options that I am also exploring is to use the `subprocess` module to perform `PowerShell` commands. I am not sure if that is a right/wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is you can use LDAP to access Active Directory and just query and retrieve that information from the AD object directly see http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1ap51a/python_and_active_directory/

Eg the Primary SMTP Address is held in the Mail property and the ProxyAddresses are held in the ProxyAddresses property

Cheers
Glen